# Hybris SOLR "no space left on device"

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrcloud

In our DEV environment, every time when I perform a full index and I check SOLR Admin Logging, I see a lot of error logs stating:

```
Index fetch failed :java.nio.file.FileSystemException: 
/var/solr/master_electronics_Product_default_shard1_replica_n4/data/index.20210625074039782: 
No space left on device
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
```

How can I free up space in SOLR?

Comment: try this "sudo apt autoremove" to remove the unused files

Comment: Your server/VM/container is out of space. That's not really related to Solr, but you'll need to make more space for Solr in some way. Exactly how you do that depends on if you can remove anything from the environment, or request a larger disk on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/test/solr_temp"

update solr.in.sh and add above command.